# Retrieving salesforce Custom Settings From marketing Cloud AMPSCRIPT

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, customsetting

In Marketing Cloud I have a Cloud Page, I need to get some infos stored in a Custom Settings in Salesforce.

Here is what I'm tryng to do:

```
%%[
 var @rs
 Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('CustomSetting__c', 'Id,customfield__c','customfield__c','=','test')
 IF NOT Empty(@rs) THEN 
      Set @row = ROW(@rs,1)
      Set @Id = FIELD(@row,"customfield__c")
 ELSE
  SET @error = "ERRORE"
 ENDIF
]%%
```

Custom Setting's visibility is set to Public and it's a Hierarchy Type.

Thanks for helping.
Cheers,
Stefano

Comment: Are you facing any errors ? Please elaborate what you would like to be fixed for this problem

Comment: Hi Rajdeep, no errors have been thrown, I can only see “Errore” which is meaning the list is empty, I am trying to get the custom setting value.

Answer (score 0):

First requirement of using Salesforce Functions in Marketing Cloud is to have a fully configured Marketing Cloud Connector Setup. I assume that's already set up in your case.

Since you're getting an empty resultset, I would recommend verifying if the data being retrieved is available in Sales Cloud/Salesforce.

```
RetrieveSalesforceObjects('CustomSetting__c', 'Id,customfield__c','customfield__c','=','test') 

would translate to the following SOQL query.

Select Id, customfield__c from CustomSetting__c where customfield__c = 'test'
```

I would recommend you run this query in developer console in Sales Cloud and see if you get a valid result back. If not, you will have to tweak your query for the right results. Let me know what you find.

Comment: Hi Rajdeep! thanks for your response, yes in SF (i am using a chrome extension called ORGanizer for Salesforce, give it a try, it's awesome).
So I can retrieve the data in Salesforce, but sadly in MC still get no results.
I think it's some sort of issues related with SF Custom Settings.